# How to convert string with commas to list with commas in Python

Tags: python, string, list

Given a string with words all ending with commas (some have spaces too):

```
WordString = 'word one, word-two, word3,'
```

How do I convert the string to a list keeping the spaces and commas?

```
WordList = ['word one,','word-two,','word3,']
```

Comment: Your output clearly shows you *not* keeping the spaces.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it does for the first 'word one'

Comment: @jonrsharpe I assume `word one`

Comment: Ah I see, not *all* of the spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `split()` method of strings and a list comprehension:

```
WordList = [s.strip() + ',' for s in WordString.split(',') if s.strip()]
```

The assumptions made here, based on your example:

- You only want to keep *interior* spaces (spaces between words), not leading/trailing spaces.
- You want to keep a comma after each string in the final list.

Comment: should add [if s != ''] to end of the list comprehension, or else you'll get an extra comma

Comment: @Lina `if s` is more pythonic, added.

Comment: @RenierDelport there's likely some extra whitespace after your final comma - try adding a `.strip()` in the `if` condition, as I've done above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
['{},'.format(i).strip() for i in WordString.split(',') if i]
```

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) uses comma separator to form a list of strings.

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to remove trailing spaces from each string of the resulted list.

**Output:**

```
>>> WordString = 'word one, word-two, word3,'
>>> 
>>> ['{},'.format(i).strip() for i in WordString.split(',') if i]
['word one,', 'word-two,', 'word3,']
```